# Can I specify a separate onClick handler for TextField's icon?

Tags: office-ui-fabric

Using  component, can I specify a separate onClick handler for a decoration icon?

The code below is not working:

```
  <TextField
    {...passwordTextFieldProps}
    iconProps={{ iconName: 'RedEye', onClick: () => this.setState({ some new state }) }}
  />
```

Answer (score 6):

Two years after the author of this post I had the same question and found a better solution.

The `onClick` event is available on the icon but is disable by default (`pointerEvents` is set to `none`).

With some styling it works (also I added a cursor shape so the icon looks "clickable" but it's optional).

```
<TextField iconProps={{ iconName: 'RedEye', style: { pointerEvents: "auto", cursor: "pointer" }, onClick: () => { ... } }} />
```

Comment: This is what i was searching! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

One option to consider would  be to render an icon *separately*:

```
<div style={{display:'flex', alignItems: 'center'}}>
    <TextField  />
    <Icon iconName="RedEye"  style={{left:'-25px',position:'relative'}} onClick={()=> console.log("Clicked")}  />
</div>
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/88komv6mo9)

Comment: I see, but considering we already have an Icon and passing some props to it would be convenient to be able to set also and onClick handler.